# How can python drive selenium to use browser find something in the page(ctrl + F) or hightlight keywords

Tags: python, selenium, browser, highlight

Now my task is getting some WebPage screen shot . I use python & selenium to achieve it. ShootScreen is finished, but the question is how to highlight keyword, in order to make shootScreen clear.

One of my idea is using browser itself function of finding in the page(<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), which can highlight keyword automatically. So who can help me?

Comment: One possible way to achieve this would be to abuse the `driver.execute_script` in order to execute JS. You can see [this Selenium for Java](http://www.ufthelp.com/2014/11/how-to-implement-highlight-in-selenium.html) example to get the general idea.

Comment: thank you. I try a variety of Javascript methods to solve it, but, sadly, I failed :(

Answer (score 0):

An expansion of my comment, a sample Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

broswer = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chromedriver')

broswer.get('www.example.com')
element = broswer.find_element_by_xpath(r'path/to/required/element')
# Or any other selection method available in selenium
broswer.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, 
                                                  "color: Red;")
```

This will change the color of the selected element to red. You can use the appropriate CSS to highlight the element instead according to your needs (you may want to use `"background-color: yellow"`).

Comment: Thank you ~ Thank you so much! But, HOW can I select the tag which contains my keywords, maybe most of them must be Chinese......